# Windows phone - binding a list to a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I am very new to Windows Phone development, and I have been trying to bind a list to the LongListSelector included in the base Pivot application, but with no success.

Here's the constructor of the main page (where the binding occurs):

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<int> testList = new List<int>();
            testList.Add(0);
            testList.Add(1);
            testList.Add(2);
            listDisplay.ItemsSource = testList;

            // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
```

And here's the XAML for the LongListSelector:

```
<vm:MainViewModel
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PivotApp2.ViewModels"
    SampleProperty="Sample Text Property Value">

    <vm:MainViewModel.Items>
        <vm:ItemViewModel x:Name="listModel" LineOne="{Binding Source}"/>
    </vm:MainViewModel.Items>

</vm:MainViewModel>
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get the binding to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's start with the View-model, we need to make data binding in this class:

```
class ViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ObservableCollection<string> Strings //It's our binding property
        {
            get
            {
                return _strings;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value==null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException();
                }
                _strings = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code we are using ObservableCollectin, which Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Then we need to add some data:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel tempViewModel = new ViewModel();
        var strings = new List<string> { "text1", "text2", "text3" };

        tempViewModel.Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>(strings);

        this.DataContext = tempViewModel;

    }
```

And finaly we need to communicate our view-model with view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"/>
```

Comment: How its possible with more than one column for list